# How to create role via aws cli with a JSON instead of explicit file

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

My operation is very simple i like to create a role using aws cli, but without external json file for example

```
aws iam create-role --role-name authenticateDeviceCrossAccountAssumeRole --assume-role-policy-document "{ 
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::984589850232:root" },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}"
```

The above one doesn't work it says **An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json**

So if try removing the double quotes am getting this error in terminal **zsh: parse error near `}'**

However if i create a file explicitly and run it works fine for ex:

```
aws iam create-role --role-name authenticateDeviceCrossAccountAssumeRole --assume-role-policy-document file://$STAGE.json
```

But for some reasons i can't add a file and run it, i want to run with plain json can someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html This should help

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, check an example like this:

```
aws iam create-role --role-name emr-serverless-job-role --assume-role-policy-document '{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "emr-serverless.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  }'
```

see how a json has been provided in-line rather than as/in a `.json` file.